# Can't add FK constraint #1215

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I saw multiple questions on this error, but I can't figure out of this problem I need assistance for this. So, my table (that display the error) have this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `services_providers` (
  `GUID_users` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `GUID_services` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `GUID` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `lastUpdated` varchar(36),
  PRIMARY KEY (`GUID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I set as `PK` the GUID of each record and as `FK` the `GUID_users` and `GUID_services`. 
The `FK` are set by this query:

```
ALTER TABLE `services_providers`
ADD CONSTRAINT `services_providers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`GUID_users`) REFERENCES `users` (`GUID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT `services_providers_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`GUID_services`) REFERENCES `services` (`GUID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

***users - structure***

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`GUID` char(36) NOT NULL,
`first_name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `id_roles` (`id_roles`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=85 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

***services - structure***

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `services` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`GUID` char(36) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
`duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `id_service_categories` (`id_service_categories`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now when I execute the alter mentioned above I get:

> 1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

I just want add as `FK` the GUID of each record from the table `users` and `services` and have as `PK` the field `GUID`.

Why happean this?

Answer (score 1):

You normally add a foreign key constraint to the primary key of the other table.  The primary keys are `id`, not `GUID`.  I would suggest that you use those columns for `services_providers`.

If you insist on using `GUID`, then declare them to be `unique`.

Comment: I add the UNIQUE to GUID set as PK but the error is still the same :\

Comment: @Sandokan . . . Here is an example of it working:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/294ab.